# Traceroute time is too long

Tags: redhat, ping, interface, ip-routing, traceroute

I m using RHEL 6.5 and eth0 interaface

Interface Ip is 100.x.x.x and when i  traceroute to 100.x.x.x it showing one hop that too ip  address of interface itself.

For eg traceroute to 100.65.111.14 from 100.66.28.75 gives
100.66.28.75 3000ms 3214ms 3245ms
It quits after this.

But when I use other than 100.x.x.x segment traceroute is morethan one hop.

Moreover i able to ping default gateway but unable to traceroute ..

Comment: Your address is in the Shared address range (`100.64.0.0/10`) that is used by ISPs for residential networks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it.I found two solutions

Add route to parrticular ip via gateway
For eg
ip route add 192.0.2.1 via 10.0.0.1 [dev ifname]

Changed the subnet mask configured to /24

Thanks